# Why does it compile when casting to an unrelated interface?

Tags: java, interface, classcastexception

```
interface Printable {}
class BlackInk {}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Printable printable = null;
        BlackInk blackInk = new BlackInk();
        printable = (Printable)blackInk;
    }
}
```

If the preceding code is compiled and run, the result is a ClassCastException at `printable = (Printable)blackInk;`. But, if Printable is changed to a class, it doesn't compile because blackInk can't be cast to Printable. Why does it compile when Printable is an interface?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The compiler does not know that this won't work: You could have a subclass of BlackInk that implements Printable. Then the cast would be fine.

In situations where the compiler knows it won't work, you will get an error.

For example, if you make BlackInk `final` (so that there can be no subclasses) you get an error.

Comment: ...and that's why Gid invented unsafe cast warnings

Answer (score 13):

According to [java language specification section: 5.5.1 **Reference Type Casting**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.1):

For a compile-time reference type `S`(source) and a compile-type reference type `T`(target); While casting conversion from `S` to `T`, **If `S` is a `class` Type**

- **If `T` is a `Class` type**:

  1. Then either `T` is a subtype of `S` **or** `S` is a subtype of `T`. Otherwise, a compile time error occurs.
  2. if there exists a supertype `X` of `T`, and a supertype `Y` of `S`, such
     that both `X` and `Y` are provably distinct parameterized types, and that the
     erasures of `X` and `Y` are the same, a *compile-time error* occurs.

     ```
     class S{}

      class T extends S{}
       ////

       S s = new S();
       T t = (T)s; // run time ClassCastException will happen but no compile time error
     ```
- **If `T` is an `Interface` type**:

  1. If `S` is not a `final` class, then, if there exists a supertype `X` of `T`, and
     a supertype `Y` of `S`, such that both `X` and `Y` are provably distinct parameterized
     types, and that the erasures of `X` and `Y` are the same, a *compile-time error* occurs.
     Otherwise, the cast is always legal at compile time (**because even if `S` does not
     implement `T`, a subclass of `S` might**)
  2. If S is a final class, then S must implement T, or a compile-time error
     occurs.

That is for your case, even if class casting is detected in compile time, Interface casting is detected in `runtime`.

Answer (score 1):

Type casting happens at `run time`(remember run time polymorphism). At compile time compiler doesn't see anything wrong with the code and compiles and at run time it tries to type cast `blackink` to `printable` and is unable to do so as `blackink` doesn't implement `printable` , hence the error.