# Why is it possible to cast Class<Demo> to Class<Example>

Tags: java, casting

Why is the below cast possible without runtime error (i.e. ClassCastException)?

```
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Type t = Example.class;
        Class<Demo> demo = (Class<Demo>) t;
        System.out.println(demo);
    }
}
```

Console:

```
class Example
```

.

```
public class Example {

}
```

Comment: You aren't really casting here, just changing the template type

Comment: What does template type mean in this context?

Comment: Two words: Type erasure. At runtime it's *really* `Class demo = (Class) t;`

Comment: Note that it *should* be giving you a *compile* warning about an unchecked cast, which would help explain why the cast does not fail at runtime (because it's unchecked!).

Comment: @BrianRoach you should write that as an answer, so that etxalpo can accept it, and so that I can upvote it.

Comment: @DavidWallace Honestly, there's a little more to it in terms of how casting works in Java and ... I need to run out to the grocery store. There's *got* to be a dup somewhere, I would imagine.

Comment: class <template-type> foo

Comment: Found it. Possible duplicate of [Why does it compile when casting to an unrelated interface?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19824941/why-does-it-compile-when-casting-to-an-unrelated-interface) - the answer that quotes the JLS in particular