# Java Customs class instance can't cast to String. Why?

Tags: java

Why the instance of A can cast to List but can not cast to String?

```
class A{}
...
A a = new A();
List list = (List)a;   //pass
String s = (String)a;  //compile error
```

Comment: Because... it's not a String.

Comment: Adding to Andy's answer List is an interface while String is class. If you call the method within list then it will throw error

Comment: But it's not a list either...

Comment: Clearly class A is not a List. so Shouldnt that also be throwing error?

Comment: But  it's also not a List

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19824941/why-does-it-compile-when-casting-to-an-unrelated-interface

Comment: Well, TIL something new. I didn't know about the difference between classes and interfaces with respect to compile-time errors and casts. Thanks @ShadowDroid for the clue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler, according to the specification, only takes the declared type of `a` into account when it does these checks for casts.

So, you write:

```
A a = new A();
```

But the compiler only considers

```
A a; // = <something>;
```

So it knows that `a` cannot be a `String`, since a class can have only one superclass (no multiple inheritance), there can't be a subclass of class `A` that is also a String.

But for interfaces this isn't true. So while we know that class `A` doesn't implement `List`, there could be a class `B` defined like this:

```
class B extends A implements List {}
```

And since the compiler only considers the declared type, it must assumes that it is also possible the you assigned `new B()` to `a`.

So, because a subclass of `A` could implement the interface `List`, the compiler can't assume that the cast to `List` always fails.

Of course the cast will fail in practice though - at runtime. But not at compile time.

Answer (score 7):

Quoting [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.10):

> It is a compile-time error if, for any two classes (**not interfaces**) Vi and Vj, Vi is not a subclass of Vj or vice versa.

`String` and `A` are unrelated classes, so it is a compile-time error. `List` is an interface, so that does not cause the same error.

Note that your assertion

> the instance of A can cast to List

Is not quite correct: `A` *cannot* be cast to `List`; it is just a runtime failure, not a compile-time failure.

Comment: Hey @ShadowDroid - I rejected your edit because I don't want to take credit for your insight. Feel free to comment, or submit as an answer, and I will happily upvote it.

Comment: I am not helping to take credit/votes. I am just interested in sharing knowledge. Anyways @Erwin posted an answer with nice detailed sample.

Answer (score 1):

A class in Java can only be cast to one of its super types, or one of the interfaces on one of its super types.

In your case, class `A` is not a subclass of `String`.  Therefore `A` cannot be cast to a `String`.  Also, `String` is a final class, so you cannot write a class `A` that could be cast to a `String`.

Java already recognizes the need to easily display classes as Strings, especially for debugging / logging purposes.  To satisfy this need, the `Object` class comes with a `toString()` method.  Since all Java classes extend from the `Object` class, all Java classes contain an implementation of the `toString()` method.

It is important to remember that the existence of a `toString()` method doesn't mean that `A` is a String, rather it means that you can get a String from `A` that somewhat describes the `A` instance.  If you find that the provided description is lacking for your purposes, you may override `A`'s `toString()` method an return a better description, like so

```
@Override
public String toString() {
  return "my better description";
}
```

As the override is written in Java, you can also include any variable or other item that you can eventually turn into a String (which since all Objects have `toString()` includes nearly anything).