# Formal definition of compatible types in Java (soundness)

Tags: java, types, casting, compilation, type-systems

I was trying to find the algorithmic definition of convertible (and thus inconvertible) types in Java.

In my opinion a CORRECT compiler should block at compile-time explicit and implicit castings between expressions having inconvertible static types, whatever the definition of inconvertible would be.

On the other hand, since it would be nice if each reference had a dynamic type which is a subtype of its static type, in order to prevent ClassCastExceptions at run-time, the compiler should always block castings between types that have no common subtypes.

A candidate definition that makes sense to me is be the following:

1. Two classes A and B are convertible iff either A is a subtype of B or B is a subtype of A
2. An interface I and a class C are convertible iff either C implements I or I and C have a common subtype (a class that implements I and extends C, possibly in an indirect way)
3. Two interfaces I1 and I2 are convertible iff they have a common subtype (a class or another interface)

However the following snippets do NOT give compilation errors (only warnings for example in IntelliJIDEA):

```
interface A {}
class B {}

class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    B b  = new B();
    A a = (A)b;    // this casting will produce a run-time error
  }
}
```

```
interface M {}
interface N {}
class A implements M {}
class B extends A {}
class C extends A implements N {}

class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    N x = new C();
    M y = (B)x;   // this casting will produce a run-time error
  }
}
```

```
interface M {}
class A implements N{}
interface N {}

class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    N x = new A();
    M y = (M)x;   // this casting will produce a run-time error
  }
}
```

In conclusion I want to understand if there is an official definition of (in)convertible types in the Java specs, and whether it has been correctly implemented in the existing compilers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19824941/why-does-it-compile-when-casting-to-an-unrelated-interface

Comment: @Ivan not really, the question is about the soundness of the type system rather than why line xy does not compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question you're asking is about the soundness of the java type system (here's a nice [intro on the topic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UXBoiqRJ6DQ)).

There's no formal definition in the case of java, but a number of reconstructions do exist, arriving at statements like *"[We were surprised](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/riccardo/courses/csu370-fa07/lect4.pdf) by the subtlety and the non-uniformity of the language semantics, especially since its [description](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/) is rather colossal, ambiguous, and erroneous."* with a tendency to consider it [by and large sound](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.30.2068&rep=rep1&type=pdf), apart from obvious glitches.

Obvious glitches stem from backwards [compatibility issues](https://hackernoon.com/java-is-unsound-28c84cb2b3f), e.g. with typed collections that were put on top of untyped collections, and always can be undermined by operations taking the untyped way. The issue of casting the OP dwells upon may be yet another flavor of the issue, since what should one think of `char c = (char)1024;`?

On the other hand [fundamental inconsistencies](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2984004) have been unearthed as well, more on the level of "*parametrically polymorphic functions that can turn any type into any type without (down)casting*". Find a discussion about what's fundamental and what's a glitch [here](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2984004), also hinting at discrepancies between the language spec and the compiler.

It may be interesting to note, that the argument is also valid for the [Scala language up to version 2.x](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2984004), and perhaps any other industry scale OO-language, only the upcoming Scala 3 gets provably [rid of them](https://www.scala-lang.org/blog/2016/02/03/essence-of-scala.html). An effort that took the contributors almost a decade and is supposed to be a novelty in the realm of object oriented languages.

Comment: Are there other AOT compilable strongly typed languages that exhibit a sound type system? For example [here]( https://dart.dev/guides/language/sound-dart) they say that Dart2's type system enjoys this property. Are there even scientific papers to prove that?

Comment: AOT? Ahead of time compilation? There's [Scala native](https://scala-native.readthedocs.io/en/v0.3.9-docs/), once that is in sync with Scala 3 that would be one, [provably](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.03814.pdf), supposedly. In the functional programming era that's more of a norm than an exception it's been said, I'd have a look at Haskell e.g. I Have no better reference at hand than [this one](https://www.cs.uaf.edu/users/chappell/public_html/class/2018_spr/cs331/docs/types_primer.html) right now.